# How to get the colour of a pixel at X,Y using c#?

Tags: c#, api

How do I get the color of a pixel at X,Y using c#?

As for the result, I can convert the results to the color format I
need.  I am sure there is an API call for this.

For any given X,Y on the monitor, I want to get the color of that
pixel.

Comment: Is this anywhere on the screen or in a window in your app?

Comment: Just the general display.  I don't care about any particular instance.

Comment: For any given X,Y on the monitor, I want to get the colour of that pixel.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To get a pixel color from the **Screen** here's code from [Pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GetPixel.html):

```
  using System;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  sealed class Win32
  {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);

      [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
      static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

      static public System.Drawing.Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y)
      {
       IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
       uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
       ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
       Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
                    (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
                    (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
       return color;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can u please explain why you did what you did in the `GetPixelColor` method? (mostly the bitwise parts) Thanks!

Comment: Pixel = 32 bits int
Getpixel obtains a 32 bits int value
using bitwise he decompose that 32 bits values into 8 bits values, so he can use the function Color.FromArgb to convert the 32 bits value into a 3 -> 8 bit colors. He is using mask's to convert the values he doesnt need with the & 0x0000FF00 (only sencond byte) and then rotate the values to be in scale 0:255

Answer (score 11):

There's [`Bitmap.GetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) for an image... is that what you're after? If not, could you say which x, y value you mean? On a control?

Note that if you *do* mean for an image, and you want to get *lots* of pixels, and you don't mind working with unsafe code, then [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx) will be a lot faster than lots of calls to `GetPixel`.

Comment: I need it from the current display, not a particular file, or instance of a paint box.

Comment: In that case I'd recomend CLaRGe's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the P/Invoke solution, you can use Graphics.CopyFromScreen to get the image data from the screen into a Graphics object. If you aren't worried about portability, however, I would recommend the P/Invoke solution.

Answer (score 2):

For ref in WPF: (usage of PointToScreen)

```
    System.Windows.Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(lightningChartUltimate1);

    if (lightningChartUltimate1.ViewXY.IsMouseOverGraphArea((int)position.X, (int)position.Y))
    {
        System.Windows.Point positionScreen = lightningChartUltimate1.PointToScreen(position);
        Color color = WindowHelper.GetPixelColor((int)positionScreen.X, (int)positionScreen.Y);
        Debug.Print(color.ToString());


      ...

      ...


public class WindowHelper
{
    // ******************************************************************
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

    static public System.Windows.Media.Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y)
    {
        IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
        Color color = Color.FromRgb(
            (byte)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
            (byte)((pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8),
            (byte)((pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16));
        return color;
    }
```

Comment: Additional info: for using `System.Windows.Media.Color` namespace you need to add PresentationCore.dll to references.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is having trouble with this and none of the solutions are working, as how it was for me, and you are in WPF, here is how I got mine working :-).

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

        public static void getColor()
        {
            IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
            uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
            ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
            System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)pixel);
            Console.WriteLine("Color is {0}", color);
        }
```