# get color of a panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to get the color of a pixel of a `Panel` (or anything else, such as a `Form`)?
(Can I do it with `Graphics`'s functions?)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean, by clicking the pixel with the mouse ? And does the form belong to the same application ?

Comment: [Here's an interesting solution to get the color of a pixel on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753132/how-do-i-get-the-colour-of-a-pixel-at-x-y-using-c)

Comment: @digEmAll: i've set a BackImage for my Form, when a button is clicked, return the color of pixel(10, 10) of my form (it's backimage)

Comment: have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753132/how-do-i-get-the-colour-of-a-pixel-at-x-y-using-c),
I created an extension method that returns the color of a control pixel, given the client coordinates of the pixel:

```
public static class ControlExts
{
    public static Color GetPixelColor(this Control c, int x, int y)
    {
        var screenCoords = c.PointToScreen(new Point(x, y));
        return Win32.GetPixelColor(screenCoords.X, screenCoords.Y);
    }
}
```

So, in your case you can do:

```
var desiredColor = myForm.GetPixelColor(10,10);
```