# Is there a pixel search function in C#?

Tags: c#, autoit

I currently have made a program in AutoIT that has [PixelSearch](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelSearch.htm) methods inside of it. Anyway, I have a pretty intense GUI that can be annoying to fill out everytime you run it, so I decided I would make a save/load settings button. It turns out that AutoIT handles file reading/writing pretty inefficiently, so writing to the file to "save" settings and reading from the file to "load" settings was out of the question. I decided to make something in C# since the FileStream class is amazing. But, to replace the AutoIT program, I need the function pixelsearch, which basically searches for a certain pixel in a rectangle/point defined. Anyone have an idea how this is created, or if there is one already how it is used?

P.S: Is there also a way that I can save the cursor's location after the user presses a certain button in C#? I was thinking of a mouseEvent of some sort.

Comment: Use PInvoke to get pixels, like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/753157/284111 You will need to write your own function to do the search, based on it, but it's not very hard.

Comment: Also, what is inefficient about save/load in autoit?

Comment: May be related to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483928/how-to-read-the-color-of-a-screen-pixel

Comment: @zespri I want it to search for a pixel in a certain area of a certain color and return the x and y coordinates. And the file writing/reading is very inefficient, you try it out and tell me how it goes :)

Comment: @Jafin I want it to search for a color in a rectangle and return the color's position (x and y coordinates)

Comment: I understand what you want to do. What problems do you have in achieving it?

Comment: Did you use `IniRead`/`IniWrite` or `RegRead`/`RegWrite`? There should be no problem with saving settings to a file...

Answer (score 0):

you certainly can save the mouse click locations, try to use the mouse events `mouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` `mouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` ... inside the function you can open a stream and write the location everytime then close it , the location is `e.Location`