# Batch Plugin / Extension to search pixels with certain color on screen

Tags: batch-file, plugins

So im wondering, is there a batch plugin like "NirCMD" that alows me to search for pixels with a certain color on screen? 
Like a If-statement.

I know it works with autoit3 but I'd like to do it with batch.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean? searching for pixels with a certain color?

Comment: Yeah like a If statement:If [Location of Pixel] = [Color of Pixel] goto whatever

Comment: Which screen, your monitor? or within a particular window of some running program? Also your question as it currently stands is not within the scope of this forum, please edit it accordingly.

Comment: It actually does not matter that much, but it would be better in a particular window of a running program.

Answer (score 1):

Stolen from [***`here`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753132/how-do-i-get-the-colour-of-a-pixel-at-x-y-using-c).Save the folowing as bat (eg. `getPixelColor.bat`):

```
 // 2>nul||@goto :batch
/*
:batch
@echo off
setlocal

:: find csc.exe
set "csc="
for /r "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\" %%# in ("*csc.exe") do  set "csc=%%#"

if not exist "%csc%" (
   echo no .net framework installed
   exit /b 10
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
   call %csc% /nologo /warn:0 /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0" || (
      exit /b %errorlevel% 
   )
)
%~n0.exe %*
endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/

  using System;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  public class Win32
  {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);

      [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
      static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

      static public System.Drawing.Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y)
      {
       IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
       uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
       ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
       Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
                    (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
                    (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
       return color;
      }

       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          int X= Int32.Parse(args[0]);
          int Y=Int32.Parse(args[1]);
          System.Console.WriteLine(GetPixelColor(X,Y));
       }
   }
```

to get the color at the desired pixel:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%C in ('getPixelColor.bat  100 150') do (
    set "pixelColor=%%C"
)
echo %pixelColor%
if "%pixelColor%" EQU "Color [A=255, R=248, G=248, B=248]" echo same as mine
```

Mind that there are no checks in the C# code (non numeric input,pixel put of screen bound and etc.) so you'll have to validate the input by yourself.And this handles only the primary monitor - if you need the secondary ones you can do additional search in stackover flow and alter the code.

To iterate all pixels you'll to get the resolution of the monitor.For windows8 and newer you can use:

```
wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription /format:value
```

For older windows versions:

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenwidth /format:value
```

Then you need to nested for loops to iterate all pixels on the screen.